# Why $e^x$ never equal $x$?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, fixed-point-theorems

Je veux savoir pourquoi $x=e^x$ n'a aucune solution dans $\Bbb R$. Lorsque j'ai essayé de tracer le graphe de la fonction $e^x$, j'ai trouvé en fait qu'elle est une fonction strictement croissante mais je ne sais pas quoi faire après.

Merci mon ami.

---

I would like to know why $x=e^x$ has no solution in $\Bbb R$? I tried to plot the function $e^x$ and I found that it is an increasing function but I do not know what to do next.

Comment: Parlez-vous anglais?

Comment: Oui je peux parler.

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, could you rephrase in English?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is easily checked, by [definition of $e^x$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition). For $x > 0$ we have 
$$ e^x = 1 + x + \sum_{k = 2}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}>x$$ and for $x \leq 0$ we have $$x \leq 0 < e^x.$$

Comment: True, and a nice approach *if* $e^x$ is defined using the power series. In many first calculus books, it is not. (One defines $\ln x$, and then defines $\exp(x)$ as the inverse function.) There are other possibilities.

Answer (score 10):

By [Bernoulli's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality),
$$ \left(1+\frac xn\right)^n \ge 1+x \qquad\text{if $n > |x|$.} $$
Letting $n\to\infty$ yields $e^x \ge 1+x > x$.

(I like this argument because it doesn't need to treat $x<0$ specially.)

Comment: The hard part is to show that $e^x \ge (1+x/n)^n$. Also, the usual elementary version of Bernoulli's inequality is shown for integer $n$; the general version is a good deal harder.

Comment: @martycohen, it's a good thing, then, that neither the inequality $e^x\ge(1+x/n)^n$, nor the general case of Bernoulli's inequality, are invoked in this answer.

Answer (score 5):

If we look at the initial value for each function $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=e^x$ we see that $f(0)=0 < g(0)=1$.

Now for $x>0$ we have $f'(x)=1$ and $g'(x) = e^x$ which tells us that $f'(x) < g'(x)$ for all $x > 0$, and so $$x \le e^x$$ for all $x \ge 0$. For negative $x$ we know that $e^x$ is strictly positive, so this tells us that $$x \le e^x$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5):

The exponential function is a convex function, since the second derivative equals the function, so it is non-negative. This implies that the graphics of $f(x)=\exp(x)$ lies above the tangent line in $x=0$, i.e.:
$$\forall \in\mathbb{R},\quad e^x \geq x+1.$$

Answer (score 2):

If $x \leq 0$, then $e^x > 0 \geq x$.

Suppose $x > 0$ and let $f(x) = e^x - x $. So $f'(x) = e^x - 1 > e^0 - 1 = 0$. Hence $f$ is increasing and since $f(0) > 0$, $f(x) = e^x - x > 0$, finally $e^x > x$.

The inequality is **strict**.